# Get and average from user input to a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am totally new to programming so my question maybe confusing but I will try to explain as best as I can.

So I build a app that take in ratings between 1-5. The result is stored in the data base. But I do not understand how to put some logic in my model class where it can retrieve that number and out output the number the users input and the overall average of the rating it was given.

This is my Model class:

```
 public class MovieReview : IValidatableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }


    [Range(1,10)]
    [Required]
    public double Rating { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(1024)]
    public string Comment { get; set; }


    [Display(Name="User Name")]
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText="anonymous")]


    //[MaxWord(5)]
    public string ReviewerName { get; set; }
    public int MovieId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if(Rating < 2 && ReviewerName.ToLower().StartsWith("keith"))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Scorry, Keith uou can't do this");
        }
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public partial class MovieReview : IValidatableObject
{
    public ICollection<AverageRating>

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AverageRating { get _AverageRating(c => c.AverageRating; set; }

}
```

}

This is my controller:

```
namespace YayOrNay.Controllers
```

{
    public class ReviewsController : Controller
    {
        YayOrNayDb _db = new YayOrNayDb();

```
    // GET: Reviews
    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "id")]int movieId)
    {
        var movie = _db.Movies.Find(movieId);
        if(movie !=null)
        {
            return View(movie);
        }
        return HttpNotFound();

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create (int movieId)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MovieReview review)
    {
       if(ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           _db.Reviews.Add(review);
           _db.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = review.MovieId });
       }
       return View(review);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit (int id)
    {
        var model = _db.Reviews.Find(id);
        return View(model);
    }

    //[Bind(Exclude = "ReviewerName")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit (MovieReview review)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Entry(review).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = review.MovieId });
        }
        return View(review);
    }



    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }   

}
```

}

And this is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<YayOrNay.Models.MovieReview>




<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rating)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comment)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReviewerName)
        </th>






        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReviewerName)
            </td>





            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |

            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

I hope this is enough information for you to understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: Here is my github account if it helps. I am struggling with this project:

https://github.com/KeithoSan/YayOrNay_V5

Comment: You just need a data access method and return the value after computation.

Comment: Read up about 'not mapped' and 'computed properties' in Entity Framework.

Comment: Do I use IEnurmable in Model class? 
IEnumerable<MovieReview> AverageRating = from a in db.MovieReview;

Comment: after alot of research I have figured out it could be this 


    public double AverageRating
        {
            get
            {
                using (MovieReview db = new MovieReview())
                {
                    var reviews = db.Rating

                        if (reviews.Count()>0)
                    {
                        double RatingAverage = (double) reviews.Average(r => r.Rating) 0;
                        return RatingAverage;
                    }
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }